# Jquery can't change div's left attribute

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a div in my code. And a javascript function that changes div's left attribute by jquery animate. The problem is when function runs, div goes left at a moment and gets back to its position! Looks like it's sticking!

I changed animate function to change the 'top' and it worked correctly. But left...

I tried other animation liberaries and still the same problem exists. So the problem is not with jquery.

any ideas?

edit:

my div:

```
<div id="divid" style="visibility:hidden;position:absolute;left:520px;top:408px;width:56px;height:56px;z-index:701;text-align: left;">
<img src="images/something.png" id="Image3" alt="" style="width:41px;height:56px;">
</div>
```

my function:

```
function changepos()
{

    $( "#divid" ).animate({left: "20px"}, 1500 );

}
```

You see guys it's simple. I really don't know what's the problem! Maybe the reason is other js files that are included in the page...

Comment: No ideas... without code lines it's just daydreams. Create a [demo](http://jsfiddle.net)

Comment: Recreate the problem in a small amount of code and post it here please.

Comment: How are you triggering the function?  What are the `position` attributes of the div and its parent divs?  Read this: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Show your html, css and js. It will be better if you give a jsfiddle link.

Comment: Could be 10 different reasons...where's the demo that replicates this

Comment: I copied code provided to [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/89xuc8jg/), removed the hidden, added a click handler, and it works fine.  Please read the [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), specifically the part about *complete and verifiable*.  The code you've provided does not reproduce the problem.

Comment: Works for me [here](http://jsfiddle.net/ykmwhjnx/).

Comment: Thank you guys I think this is some kind of problem that I have to handle it on my own.

Comment: Note: animate left *moves to that position* - it doesn't *move by* that amount

Answer (score 1):

Remove "visibility:hidden" from your inline css.

You should see the image move from right to left (fyi I did increase 20px to 200px)

```
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.4.min.js"></script>
    <script>
    $( document ).ready(function() {

            $( "#buttonTest" ).click(function() {       
              changepos();
            });

            function changepos()
            {
                $( "#divid" ).animate({left: "200px"}, 1500 );
        }
    });
    </script>

    <input type="button" id="buttonTest" value="Press Me"/>

    <div id="divid" style="position:absolute;left:520px;top:408px;width:56px;height:56px;z-index:701;text-align: left;">
        <img src="images/test.jpg" id="Image3" alt="" style="width:41px;height:56px;">
    </div>
```